# Not getting desired output in list

Tags: python, list, loops, parsing, tuples

```
_list = ['Adarsh Kumar Goel', 'Pilibhit Tiger Reserve', 'Sheikha Bodour Bint Sultan Al Qasimi', 'Saudi Central Bank', 'Vijay Kumar Sinha', 'Odisha', 'Niger', 'Qatar', '6000 cr', 'Greg Barclay', 'Tripura', 'Geneva', 'Thaawarchand Gehlot', 'V.K. Saraswat', 'SBI']

c = [('Adarsh Kumar Goel', 'Swatanter Kumar', 'Lokeshwar Singh Panta', 'K. Ramakrishnan', 'Saibal Dasgupta'),
     ('Panna Tiger Reserve', 'Rajaji Tiger reserve', 'Pilibhit Tiger Reserve', 'Manas Tiger Reserve', 'Corbett Tiger Reserve'),
     ('Haifaa Al Mansour', 'Nour El Sherbini', 'Sheikha Bodour Bint Sultan Al Qasimi', 'Sheikha Aisha bint Rashid Al Khalifa', 'Sheikha Mozah Al Maktoum'),
     ('Bank of Saudi', 'Saudi Central Bank', 'Central Bank of Saudi', 'Reserve Bank of Saudi Arab', 'Federal Bank of Saudi'),
     ('Sushil Modi', 'Vijay Kumar Sinha', 'Renu Devi', 'Tejashwi Yadav', 'Tar Kishor Prasad'),
     ('Maharashtra', 'Kerala', 'Madhya Pradesh', 'Odisha', 'Tripura'),
     ('Kenya', 'Brazil', 'Ethiopia', 'Niger', 'Rwanda'),
     ('Bahrain', 'Qatar', 'Jordan', 'UAE', 'Saudi Arabia'),
     ('2000 cr', '4000 cr', '6000 cr', '7500 cr', '10,000 cr'),
     ('Shashank Manohar', 'Greg Barclay', 'Imran Khwaja', 'Anil Kumble', 'Manu Sawhney'),
     ('Odisha', 'Madhya Pradesh', 'Tripura', 'Goa', 'Uttar Pradesh'),
     ('Zurich', 'Istanbul', 'Geneva', 'New York', 'Kabul'),
     ('Narendra Modi', 'Thaawarchand Gehlot', 'Ravi Shankar Prasad', 'Narendra Singh Tomar', 'Smriti Irani'),
     ('Jyoti Sinha', 'V.K. Saraswat', 'Vinod Kumar Yadav', 'Amitabh Kant', 'Rajiv Kumar'),
     ('Axis Bank', 'PNB', 'SBI', 'HDFC', 'RBL Bank')]

temp = []
answers = []
for x in _list:
    for z in range(len(c)):
        for y in range(len(c[z])):
            if c[z][y] == x:
                pdb.set_trace()
                temp.append(c[z][y])
                answers.append(y+1)
```

Why am I getting this output twice in some values I don't know where I went wrong

```
temp = ['Adarsh Kumar Goel', 'Pilibhit Tiger Reserve', 'Sheikha Bodour Bint Sultan Al Qasimi', 'Saudi Central Bank', 'Vijay Kumar Sinha', 'Odisha', 'Odisha', 'Niger', 'Qatar', '6000 cr', 'Greg Barclay', 'Tripura', 'Tripura', 'Geneva', 'Thaawarchand Gehlot', 'V.K. Saraswat', 'SBI']
```

I am getting unexpected output:

`answers = [1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3]`

This answers list is unexpected and undesired.

The problem is that I expect the output

```
[1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3]
```

However, the output `[1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 3]` is also valid, how can I fix my code so that I get at least one of the valid outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your condition from :

```
    if c[z][y] == x:
        pdb.set_trace()
        temp.append(c[z][y])
        answers.append(y+1)
```

to:

```
      if c[z][y] == x: 
            pdb.set_trace()
            if x not in temp:
               temp.append(c[z][y])
               answers.append(y+1)
```

Only add do the temp list if it not yet there.

Running example:

```
_list = ['Adarsh Kumar Goel', 'Pilibhit Tiger Reserve', 'Sheikha Bodour Bint Sultan Al Qasimi', 'Saudi Central Bank', 'Vijay Kumar Sinha', 'Odisha', 'Niger', 'Qatar', '6000 cr', 'Greg Barclay', 'Tripura', 'Geneva', 'Thaawarchand Gehlot', 'V.K. Saraswat', 'SBI']

c = [('Adarsh Kumar Goel', 'Swatanter Kumar', 'Lokeshwar Singh Panta', 'K. Ramakrishnan', 'Saibal Dasgupta'), ('Panna Tiger Reserve', 'Rajaji Tiger reserve', 'Pilibhit Tiger Reserve', 'Manas Tiger Reserve', 'Corbett Tiger Reserve'), ('Haifaa Al Mansour', 'Nour El Sherbini', 'Sheikha Bodour Bint Sultan Al Qasimi', 'Sheikha Aisha bint Rashid Al Khalifa', 'Sheikha Mozah Al Maktoum'), ('Bank of Saudi', 'Saudi Central Bank', 'Central Bank of Saudi', 'Reserve Bank of Saudi Arab', 'Federal Bank of Saudi'), ('Sushil Modi', 'Vijay Kumar Sinha', 'Renu Devi', 'Tejashwi Yadav', 'Tar Kishor Prasad'), ('Maharashtra', 'Kerala', 'Madhya Pradesh', 'Odisha', 'Tripura'), ('Kenya', 'Brazil', 'Ethiopia', 'Niger', 'Rwanda'), ('Bahrain', 'Qatar', 'Jordan', 'UAE', 'Saudi Arabia'), ('2000 cr', '4000 cr', '6000 cr', '7500 cr', '10,000 cr'), ('Shashank Manohar', 'Greg Barclay', 'Imran Khwaja', 'Anil Kumble', 'Manu Sawhney'), ('Odisha', 'Madhya Pradesh', 'Tripura', 'Goa', 'Uttar Pradesh'), ('Zurich', 'Istanbul', 'Geneva', 'New York', 'Kabul'), ('Narendra Modi', 'Thaawarchand Gehlot', 'Ravi Shankar Prasad', 'Narendra Singh Tomar', 'Smriti Irani'), ('Jyoti Sinha', 'V.K. Saraswat', 'Vinod Kumar Yadav', 'Amitabh Kant', 'Rajiv Kumar'), ('Axis Bank', 'PNB', 'SBI', 'HDFC', 'RBL Bank')]

    temp = []
    answers = []
    for x in _list:
        for z in range(len(c)):
            for y in range(len(c[z])):
                if c[z][y] == x:
                    if x not in temp:
                        temp.append(c[z][y])
                        answers.append(y+1)
    
    assert temp == _list
    assert answers == [1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 3]
    print(temp)
    print(answers)
```

Btw: IMO it is better not to do `answers.append(y+1)` but rather  `answers.append(y)`, because arrays in computers start from 0, so you can avoid some misunderstandings by not adding +1 to the index. Unless, that index y+1 is only used to show data to a non programmer.

**A better approach:**

However, since, in your `c` list you have some entries that are duplicated, IMO you are better off using a map to keep the multiple possible answers for a given key:

```
temp = []
answers = {}
for x in _list:
    for z in range(len(c)):
        for y in range(len(c[z])):
            if c[z][y] == x:
                if x not in temp:
                    temp.append(c[z][y])
                    answers[x] = [y+1]
                elif x in temp:
                    answers[x].append(y + 1)

assert temp == _list 
print(_list)
print(answers)
```

**Output**:

```
{'Adarsh Kumar Goel': [1], 'Pilibhit Tiger Reserve': [3], 'Sheikha Bodour Bint Sultan Al Qasimi': [3], 'Saudi Central Bank': [2], 'Vijay Kumar Sinha': [2], 'Odisha': [4, 1], 'Niger': [4], 'Qatar': [2], '6000 cr': [3], 'Greg Barclay': [2], 'Tripura': [5, 3], 'Geneva': [3], 'Thaawarchand Gehlot': [2], 'V.K. Saraswat': [2], 'SBI': [3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example the entry `Odisha` appears twice inside the array `c`. An easy fix would be to make the `temp` array a `set` instead. That way you'll never have duplicates.

```
temp = set()
...
temp.add(c[z][y])  # Will do nothing if a value is already present
```

Or depending how you want to use the program you might want to make sure duplicate values don't get processed at all.

```
if c[z][y] in temp:
    continue
```

Comment: It is okay to have two similar values but not one when it is not needed that means somethings going wrong in the code

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate, what the intended outcome would be then

Comment: intended outcome is in the _list, but only the number/indexes like in answers

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting this output twice in some values

Some values appear more than once in `c`. For example `'Odisha'` is at:

```
>>> c[5][3]
'Odisha'
>>> c[10][0]
'Odisha'
```

Your inner loops `for z in..,: for y in...:` search through **all** items in `c` for each item in `_list` so both those *locations* are found and they meet the criteria (`c[z][y] == x`) to be included in `temp`.

Since you have not explained what you are trying to do - the *rules* you are trying to implement - it isn't clear how to *fix* your code.

One solution might be to stop the search once a match has been found.

```
def g(_list,c):
    temp = []
    answers = []
    for x in _list:
        for sub in c:
            try:
                answers.append(sub.index(x) + 1)
                temp.append(x)
                break    # stop the search
            except ValueError:
                continue
    return temp,answers
```

Comment: I can see the problem now, thank you for your help sir i really appreciate it